# ejabberd: Referencing users when multiple hosts are used

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm investigating how to sett up an ejabberd cluster with two separate hosts:

- host1.mydomain.com
- host2.mydomain.com

These two hosts can interact with each other; but a subset of users can only interact with host2.

Is there a way ensure all users have username@xmpp.mydomain.com rather than responding to username@host1.mydomain.com and otherusername@host2.mydomain.com - Or is this the default scenario?

I need it to be predictable so I can message the user.

Answer (score 0):

A cluster setup can run on several servers as a single domain. That's the purpose of clustering. So yes, if you create a cluster with the two hosts, the user can be in the same domain.

Please, read ejabberd documentation to learn about setting up a cluster: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/

That said, if you want to prevent some users to talk with each other, you will need to write custom module for that, as chat policy on a single domain is not a standard feature.